# Kial oni ne uzu la volitivon post ‘esperi’?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

En la nederlanda libro “*Esperanto Grammatica met oefeningen*” (“Esperanta Gramatiko kun ekzercoj”) de *Roel Haveman* kaj *Arjen-Sjoerd de Vries* skribiĝas la jena en la sekcio pri la volitivo:

> Post *esperi* (…) kaj *timi* (…) la volitivo ne estas uzata. Oni eble povas senti tion, se oni ŝanĝas la frazon en la rektan parolon. Tiam iom klariĝas, ke ‘espero’ kaj ‘timo’ temas pri faktaj, kaj ne (ne)dezirataj, situacioj. Do:
>   *Ni esperas, ke niaj manĝaĵoj bone gustos al vi.* (…)
>   (*Ni esperas: ‘niaj manĝaĵoj bone gustos al vi.’*)
>   *Ni timas, ke niaj manĝaĵoj malbone gustos al vi.* (…)
>   (*Ni timas: ‘niaj manĝaĵoj malbone gustos al vi.’*)

(La traduko estas mia, la emfazo ne. La emfazo originale estas in Esperanto. La ellasitaj partoj estis nederlandaj tradukoj.)

Mi ne povas ‘senti’, ke espero temas pri faktaj situacioj. Se mi esperas ion, mi certe volas, ke tio okazu aŭ estiĝu. Kompreneble, mi esperas nerealajn aferojn! Kiel tiuj aferoj povas esti faktaj? Do tio ŝajnas bona uzo por la volitivo laŭ mi. Aliflanke, mi antaŭe neniam pensis pri la ebleco uzi la volitivon por timo. Mi simple neniam faras tion intuicie.

Do: Kial oni ne uzu la volitivon en subpropozicioj, subordigitaj al propozicio kun espero aŭ timo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oni ja povas uzi la volitivon post "esperi".

Zamenhof ŝajne ne uzis la volitivon post "esperi", sed ja post "voli". Tio verŝajne estas la kialo por la klarigoj en la nederlanda libro, kiun vi citas. Sed jam la samtempuloj de Zamenhof komencis uzi la volitivon post "esperi", kaj nuntempe tio estas konsiderata tute normala. Jen kelkaj ekzemploj de bonaj aŭtoroj el diversaj tempoj:

> Ni devas labori, por ke estu pli da loko ol ni iam esperas, ke ĝi havu (Langlet/Luin, 1895)
>   ĉu oni povas esperi, ke ĉi tiu historie signifa verko estu baldaŭ represata (Valienne, 1907)
>   poste ili povas trankvile sidi apud la truo kaj esperi, ke iu malsata fiŝo englutu la muŝlarvon kaj hokon (Manotao, 1997-2003)

Kaj eble plej konvinke, eĉ [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html#i-zd8) instruas la eblon uzi la volitivon post "esperi":

> Mi tre esperas, ke lia barbo ne kresku

Post "timi" oni efektive ne uzas la volitivon, ĉar tio ne vere estas senchava, kiel vi jam mem rimarikis. Tio, kion oni timas, je ne estas dezirata aŭ celata.

Comment: Dankon pro tio! Fakte, nun mi estas iom konfuzata pri tio, kio estas la diferenco inter *esperi+-u* kaj *esperi+-os*… Mi pensas, ke la kialo, ke ‘timi’ estas menciita, estas, ke ankaŭ negacioj de deziroj ktp estu en la volitivo.

Comment: @Joffysloffy: Ne estas vera signifodiferenco inter *esperi+-u* kaj *esperi+-os*. Eble kelkaj sentas nuancan diferencon, sed mi ne sentas tian diferencon (kaj mi ja estas tre sperta parolanto de Esperanto, kiu uzas Esperanton ĉiutage kaj estas membro de la Akadmeio de Esperanto). Do mi malrekomendus provi esprimi iun nuancan diferencon per tiu elekto de la verba finaĵo. Oni simple konsideru la du esprimmanierojn sinonimaj.

Comment: @MarcosCramer Tute klare! Dankon pro la klarigo!

Comment: @Joffysloffy: Ĉar vi ŝajne konsentas kun mia klarigo, mi petas vin marki mian respondon kiel plej bonan. La respondo de Hans Adler, kiu nuntempe estas markite de vi kiel plej bona respondo, ja baziĝas sur la erara kredo, ke vere ne eblas uzi la volitivon post "esperi".

Comment: @MarcosCramer Up! Vi ja pravas, sed mi forgesis pri tio!

Answer (score 5):

Mi ne estas eksperto (ĉi tiu estas mia unua teksto en Esperanto post nur malmultaj semajnoj kun Duolingo!), sed aperas al mi ke la ekzemploj en la libro estas pli klara ol la ekspliko.

*Voli, insisti, peti, kredi, esperi, timi, ...* estas verboj, kiuj povas enkonduki nerektan parolon. En lingvo sen nerekta parolo, ni bezonus aliajn trukojn.

Tipaj ekzemploj:

- *Mi volas, ke vi **aŭskultu** min. → **Aŭskultu** min! Mi volas ĝin.*
- *Mi insistas, ke vi **restu** kaj **trinku** teon. →  **Restu** kaj **trinku** teon! Mi insistas pri ĝin.*
- *Mi petas, ke vi ne plu **skribu** al mi. → Ne plu **skribu** al mi! Mi petas ĝin.*
- *Mi kredas, ke pastaĵoj **estas** sanktaj. → Ĉu pastaĵoj **estas** sanktoj? Mi kredas ĝin.*
- *Mi esperas, ke **pluvos**. → Ĉu **pluvos**? Mi esperas ĝin.*
- *Mi timas, ke mi **perdis** miajn ŝlosilojn. → Ĉu mi **perdis** miajn  ŝlosilojn? Mi timis ĝin.*

Same kiel en la ekzemploj, *aŭskulti, insisti* kaj *peti* norme esprimas komandon aŭ ordonon. Oni povas uzi tiuj verboj en metafora senco, sed tiu estas derivita senco por emfazi ion. La emfazo estas pli efika se oni konservas la volitivon/imperativon:

- *Mi volas, ke mia ŝlosilo ne **estu** en la ŝlosita aŭto. → Ŝlosilo mia, ne **estu** en la ŝlosita aŭto! Mi (ne) volas ĝin.*

Same kiel en la ekzemploj, *kredi, esperi* kaj *timi* norme esprimas konjektoj pri la realo, kvankam foje kolorigitaj de (mal)deziro. Oni povas uzi tiuj verboj en metafora senco por esprimi ordonoj, sed tiu estas derivita senco por bonmanieri. Estas pli ĝentila se oni konservas la indikativon:

- *Mi esperas, ke vi nun **komencis** fari viajn hejmtaskojn. →  Ĉu vi nun **komencis** fari viajn hejmtaskojn? Mi esperas ĝin.*

Se oni uzus la imperativon, estus malpli ĝentila, kaj la verbo *esperi* aŭ *kredi* estus netaŭga:

- *Mi esperas(???), ke vi nun **komencu** fari viajn hejmtaskojn. →  **Komencu** fari viajn hejmtaskojn! Mi esperas(???) ĝin.*
- *Mi kredas(???), ke pastaĵoj **estu** sanktaj. → Pastaĵoj **estu** sanktoj! Mi kredas(???) ĝin.*

Malgraŭ tio, mi kredas, ke ĉi tiu estas bona maniero por esprimi ŝajnĝentilan ordonon. Sed kun *timi* estus totale bizara:

- *Mi timas, ke mi **perdu**(???) miajn ŝlosilojn. → Mi **perdu**(???) miajn  ŝlosilojn! Mi timis ĝin.*

Ankaŭ kun *esperi*, la imperativo eblas bizari:

- *Mi esperas, ke **pluvu**(???). → **Pluvu**(???)! Mi esperas(???) ĝin.*
- *Ni esperas, ke niaj manĝaĵoj bone **gustu**(???) al vi. → Manĝaĵoj, bone **gustu**(???) al li/ŝi/ili! Mi esperas(???) ĝin.*

Comment: Dividante la frazojn tiumaniere, vi ja pli klarigas la aferon ol la libro! Dankon pro tio; mi pensas, ke mi komprenas!

Answer (score 3):

Oni ja povas uzi u-verbon post esperi'. PMEG enhavas kelkajn ekzemplojn:

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html#i-zd8