# How do we translate “to do” at the end of a sentence?

Tags: translation

In English, for example, we can say something like the following sentences.

> I don't like to exercise, but I do.

> I hope he learns Esperanto, but I don't think he will.

Neither *(to) exercise* nor *(to) learn* has been repeated.
How does this work in Esperanto? Do we simply use *fari*?

(Also, what is the grammatical term for this?)

Comment: I think other languages that don't use auxiliary verbs so much will be similar, so I've copied the question over to the French StackExchange too: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21975/how-do-we-translate-to-do-at-the-end-of-a-sentence

Answer (score 5):

I would use *fari ĝin* in both of these situations.

*Mi ne ŝatas ekzerci, sed mi faras ĝin.*

*Mi esperas, ke li lernas Esperanton, sed mi pensas, ke li ne faros ĝin.*

Comment: Shouldn't it be *Mi esperas, ke li *lernu**… ?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev Funny that there was a question exactly about that topic ☺ http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/292/kial-oni-ne-uzu-la-volitivon-post-esperi

Comment: @NeilRoberts I've seen that, and that is why I commented on that here. :)

Comment: This response pretty much matches what they recommended on the French StackExchange so I think it is probably right in Esperanto too.